# Send custom object using Android native Binder

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-binder

I can only find examples for Java regarding Parcelable.
My goal is to create a simple service and client in native C++ ( not NDK ), that will use Binder to receive and send serialized custom objects.

```
MyClass
+ std::string
+ enum
+ int
+ bool
```

Comment: What do you mind with no NDK? Is allowed to use JNI?

Comment: It seems Parcelable.h interface is available from Android 6.0 and above and i'm using 5.1.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get C++ Code working in android without the NDK. It is the toolchain / cross compiler used to get the code working. It also includes the (almost always needed) stl.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Android 5.1 I'll stick to what's available on Lollipop. There are better tools like [aidl-cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/tools/aidl/+/brillo-m10-dev/docs/aidl-cpp.md) to accomplish this which saves a lot of the hassle of hand-rolling boiler-plate codes.

First, craft the Interface for the service in `IFooService.h`.

```
class IFooService: public IInterface {
    public:
        DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(FooService);
        virtual int myFunc(const String8& str, int enumParam, int intParam, int boolParam) = 0;

};
```

Then write the *marshalling* code for the service, implementing a function as per the requirements in the question

```
class BnFooService: public BnInterface<IFooService>
{
public:
    virtual status_t    onTransact( uint32_t code,
                                    const Parcel& data,
                                    Parcel* reply,
                                    uint32_t flags = 0);
};

enum {
    MY_FUNC = IBinder::FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION,
};

/* BinderProxy code, for clients of the service to call into the service and have
   the paremeters marshalled properly across the Binder interface. Executes in the
   client process context
 
*/
class BpFooService: public BpInterface<IFooService> {
public:
    virtual int myFunc(const String8& str, int enumParam, int intParam, int boolParam) {
        //2 Parcel objects, 1 to write the data to and another to receive it in
        Parcel data, reply;
        //This serves as the token for the Binder framework for a sanity check
        data.writeInterfaceToken(IFooService::getInterfaceDescriptor());
        data.writeString8(str);
        data.writeInt32(enumParam);
        data.writeInt32(intParam);
        data.writeInt32(boolParam);
        return remote()->transact(MY_FUNC, data, &reply);
    }
}

IMPLEMENT_META_INTERFACE(MediaPlayerService, "com.somedomain.IFooService");

/* Actual Binder implementation of the service which unpacks the data from the
   incoming Parcel and handles the call accordingly     
*/
status_t BnFooService::onTransact(uint32_t code, const Parcel& data, Parcel* reply, uint32_t flags) {
    switch (code) {
        case MY_FUNC: {
            //The same token is checked
            CHECK_INTERFACE(IFooService, data, reply);
            //Read off in exact same order as written to the data Parcel above
            String8 str = data.readString8();
            int enumParam = data.readInt32();
            int intParam = data.readInt32();
            int boolParam = data.readInt32();
            reply->writeInt32(myFunc(str, enumParam, intParam, boolParam));
            return NO_ERROR;
        }
        break;
    default:
        
}
```

Then create the `main_foo.cpp` with some code as follows which serves as the entry point for the service process:

```
int main() {
    if(!FooService::publish()) { //Call into your code to register with ServiceManager
        ALOGE("Can't instantiate FooService! Exiting");
        return 1;
    }
    ProcessState::self()->startThreadPool(); //Required for the binder threads
    IPCThreadState::self()->joinThreadPool(); //Infinite loop that waits for inbound connections
}
```

And, finally, implement the interface for the service in `FooService.cpp`

```
bool FooService::publish() {
    defaultServiceManager()->addService(String16("foo_service"), new FooService());
    sp<IBinder> binder = defaultServiceManager()->checkService(String16("foo_service"));
    while(binder == NULL && /*some upper time limit*/){
        ALOGI("Waiting for foo_service");
    }
    return binder != NULL;
}

int FooService::myFunc(const String8& str, int enumParam, int intParam, int boolParam) {
    //business logic
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that this is **not** code that's meant for regular application developers but instead for ***native services*** running in the Android Framework like `InputFlinger`, `SurfaceFlinger` etc. This code requires Framework Header files like `Parcel.h`, `IInterface.h` etc. which aren't available in an SDK.